# Что такое маска сети /8, /16, /24, /32 и для чего это нужно?

Tags: сеть, tcp-ip, протоколы

Что это такое, для чего используется, и как считать маску сети?

Comment: Число указывает количество единичных битов неразреженной маски. Используется для определения по адресу хоста: адреса сети, адреса бродкаста сети, факта нахождения в одной сети с другим хостом. И для решения обратных задач.

Comment: @Mr.Brightside Там речь про диапазоны для фильтрации на сервере. Здесь же предположу, что речь о настройке интерфейса на клиенте.

Comment: @Arhad Автор в вопросе этого _не_ указал. По приведенной ссылке можно найти информацию о том, "что такое /24?" и "как считать?", что является прямыми ответами на вопросы автора. Если вопрос будет обновлен, станет яснее.

Comment: Зато первая же ссылка из того ответа ведет на википедию https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8 где подробно написано что это такое и как считается

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы понять, зачем нужна маска сети, рассмотрим следующий пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это настольный компьютер, и на нём есть:

1. Кабель до маршрутизатора, адрес 192.168.0.102/24;
2. Виртуальная сеть для виртуальных машин, адрес 192.168.56.1/24;
3. Wi-Fi адаптер, адрес динамический;
4. Туннель до удалённой сети, адрес 10.0.64.2/8.

Это наши интерфейсы во внешний мир, на каждый из которых можно отправить произвольный пакет.

Перейдём к проблеме. Пусть у нас на виртуальной машине по адресу 192.168.56.15 есть некий сайт. Открываем браузер, вводим `http://192.168.56.15/` и нажимаем «Ввод». В результате операционная система получает от браузера поток байт с указанием переслать его по конкретному адресу. Вопрос: на какой из четырёх интерфейсов надо отправить данные?

Здесь на сцену и выходят маски сетей. В нашем случае они прописаны у каждого интерфейса и показывают, какую часть его адреса считать «родовой» (т. е. адресом сети, которая за ним находится). На интерфейс надо отправлять только те пакеты, начало чьих адресов совпадает с его «родовой» частью. Отсчёт ведётся в битах; точки же адреса отделяют восьмибитные (однобайтные) группы:

> ```
>      192   .    168   .     56    .    15
>
>   11000000   10101000    00111000   00001111
>   ^                                        ^
>  Старший бит                             Младший бит
>
>   --------->
>   Биты маски отсчитываются в этом направлении
>              8           16         24
> ```

В случае нашего сайта поиск пути будет выглядеть так:

1. Пробуем кабель до маршрутизатора. Маска сети `/24` (т. е. три байта адреса) — пересылаем сюда всё, адресованное на `192.168.0.xxx` (каждое число — это один байт, 0-255). Проверяем совпадение: `192.168.0.15 ≠ 192.168.56.xxx` (отличие в третьем числе), значит идём дальше.
2. Пробуем сеть виртуальных машин. Маска сети тоже `/24` (т. е. три байта адреса) — пересылаем сюда всё, адресованное на `192.168.56.xxx`. Проверяем совпадение: `192.168.56.15 = 192.168.56.xxx`. Раз полное совпадение, значит шлём пакет туда.

То есть маски сетей являются фильтрами адресов, используемыми при маршрутизации, (определении направления отправки пакета).